# MAMP Pro 3.2 upgrade now MySQL fails to start (Yosemite)

Tags: mysql, upgrade, mamp-pro

I just upgraded MAMP PRO to 3.2 and when restarting the server I got the MySQL error. MAMP then popped a message saying there was an upgrade to 3.2.1 - I was hoping they found this bug and 3.2.1 included the fix.. no such luck.

Upgraded to 3.2.1 and when starting the server I get the MySQL failed to start error. Details from the log are as follows:

```
150501 17:58:26 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
150501 17:58:27 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
150501 17:58:27 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
150501 17:58:27 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150501 17:58:27 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150501 17:58:27 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150501 17:58:27 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
150501 17:58:27 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150501 17:58:27 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
150501 17:58:27  InnoDB: Retrying to lock the first data file
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or log files.
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 35
```

I went to the Mamp Pro forum to read and post,.. but they're directing everyone to post support questions here. Nice. Great way to get a free support system for a paid, commercial product.

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging I came across another post and this worked:

```
killall -9 mysqld
```

Run it from terminal.. it will kill all instances of MySQL, which is what was (apparenting) causing the failure.. it was already running?!?!